# Wine video quality

Tags: wine, video

Have a IPCamera client (Vstarcam Super Client) that is running under wine1.8-i386. The system is Lubuntu 14.04. I can't find intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.3_amd64.deb so running under stock (in release) GPU drivers.

Application is running normally, but the quality of the picture is much poor than such under native Windows setup.

If the same stream is played under MPlayer the picture is good.

How it (quality) may be improved under wine?

Here is a screen attached to show the problem. There are mess of black lines (overcontrasted pixels)...
[image: main screen]

Comment: This will require specific knowledge of wine settings and windows drivers. I would suggest asking this on the wine forums ( .https://forum.winehq.org/ )  Your problem is not likely to be fixed with something in Ubuntu ;)